# Programmatically check whether GPS is enabled or not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps

How can I check whether GPS is enabled or not on the iPhone?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]

Returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device.

Comment: thanks for the solution....Is there any thing more to check for GPS....Actually i was trying to learn about mapkit, Initially i need to check for GPS..this helped me doing that....is there anything more i need to learn....thanks for the response

Comment: this is not equivalent to detecting if gps is enabled. Location services will return true if you have wifi on, which gives you an approximate location of your position however if you are using airplane mode the true gps is in fact disabled, and assisted gps is being used.